# How to allow users to draw throughout my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch

I have implemented the following code which allows the user to draw on an imageView. I would like to implement this throughout my app but would prefer not to keep copying and pasting.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
pointCurrent = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pointNext = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pointCurrent.x, pointCurrent.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pointNext.x, pointNext.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
pointCurrent = pointNext;
}
```

So far I have tried to create a category but I'm unsure if this is the right way to go about it. Do I make a custom method and try to call that in the other classes or am I barking up the wrong tree? Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this question.

Comment: You could add this code to a custom imageView class, and make all your image views subclasses of that class.

Comment: @rdelmar my old friend! :) So all I'd have to do is make a property of the imageView, synthesize it, subclass it in Interface Builder and then it would work? Or do I have to call methods somewhere? I'll give it a bash now.

Comment: You don't need to make anything a property (and you never need to use @synthesize any more). Just create the class with your code, and set any image views you add in IB to be that class. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Property 'view' not found on object of type 'drawing *' (that's what I've called the custom class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little, because I was getting that same error that you mention in your comment. This code worked for me.

```
@interface RDImageView ()
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint pointCurrent;
@end

@implementation RDImageView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.pointCurrent = [touch locationInView:self];

}



- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointNext = [touch locationInView:self];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.image drawInRect:self.bounds];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1,1, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.pointCurrent.x, self.pointCurrent.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), pointNext.x, pointNext.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.pointCurrent = pointNext;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! So if you make the properties nonatomic, you don't have to synthesize them anymore?

Comment: @RobW, no, making them nonatomic has nothing to do with it. There were changes to the complier a while back that added automatic synthesizing. If you have a property called prop, then it gives you an ivar of _prop (so the complier does the same thing as if you had written "@synthesize prop = _prop").

Comment: If I wish to clear the drawings I've just made, I used to write imageView.image = nil; is there a neater way to do this now?

Comment: @RobW, no, I think that's as neat as it gets.